# Do we do something IN or AT a certain country (i.e. Spain)?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Do we do something in a country or at a certain country?

For example:

> 1. I'm marketing this program '**in**' Spain.

or

> 2. I'm marketing this program '**at**' Spain.

Comment: I think [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Spain%2C+at+Spain&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) might help settle the matter in your mind.

Comment: @J.R.: I don't think that n-gram describes this situation very well. "market the program in Spain" is definitely a good choice for a plain locative, when you are in Spain and marketing the program. It is not a good choice when Spain is your *target* and not your location, akin to "aim a projectile at Spain" (perfectly grammatical, though not represented in your n-gram). I must say I am unsure of the correct answer here ("to Spain"? "for Spanish people"? or even "at Spain"?), but it is not as simple as "which of the two locative markers fits a country better".

Comment: @Amadan - I didn't say "at Spain" is never grammatical. Neither does the ngram. The ngram has links to *both* usages, and any curious learner can click on [links](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22at+spain%22&lr=lang_en&safe=off&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=XAn6VY6XHoWy-QHp4ZyQAg&start=20&sa=N) beneath the chart and find examples of valid usages for either expression. However, as the ngram suggests, I think it's easier to think of examples where *in Spain" is preferred over "at Spain", rather than the other way around.

Comment: @J.R. Sure, if you click the links, you can get a more balanced story. Do you think everyone does? The graph by itself is very misleading, with "at Spain" being flush with the x-axis. I know you didn't say "at Spain" is ungrammatical, but can you honestly say it is not heavily implied in your dozen-word comment? And as I said before, it says nothing of the context, as the verb and the intended meaning is quite relevant (even decisive). "live in Spain" is a no-brainer; "attack in Spain" is not. The fact that "in Spain" is more common in general says nothing about its collocation with "market".

Comment: @Amadan - My comment was only meant to be a nudge in the right direction. If I wanted to say more, I would have left an answer instead. Perhaps **you** should leave an answer; you have a lot of insightful thoughts on this. (You can do whatever you want, but I think your energy would be better spent writing a good answer as opposed to debating me about the shortcomings of my comment.)

Comment: @J.R.: Sorry, that was not my intention at start - I just noticed that neither your +4 comment, nor the current +1 answer explore the possibility of a non-locative meaning, and wanted to point out how it might affect the answer. But it is just a comment because, as I said above, I don't actually know what would be most correct idiom for the meaning I had in mind (targeting a market campaign at another country), so by StackExchange rules it should not be a submitted answer. If I came across as confrontational, I apologise - as I said, I just wanted to offer an unexplored perspective.

Comment: Fair enough. One more thing: that red line on the ngram may look like it's "flush with the x-axis," but those who know about ngrams realize that the presence of the line indicates that there **are** hits. If there are no hits at all, [the ngram will say so](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Spain%2Cat+Spain%2C+Amadan+Spain&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: It is a common problem. While defining a country it should be used with "in" there is a graphical definition for this that you can find by google search.

Answer (score 4):

You want "in". Generally, "At" is used for a specific location, and "in" is used for a large place that contains specific locations.

A country is big enough that it is regarded as a large place. Note that the smaller you get, the fuzzier this distinction becomes. For example, [a city might qualify for either "at" or "in" depending on context](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/124775/12894).

Comment: *At* is used for points, not areas.  A country is typically too big to be considered a point but there are limited contexts where it may work, like nuclear war simulations or aliens attacking the earth (*their misslie was aimed at Spain*).